# Conversion of DVC-PRO HD 1080, any free tool?

Tags: conversion, dvd, encoding, hdvideo

Is there any free (as in beer, and if it's possible as in bird) tool to convert a dvd in the format DVC-PRO HD 1080 to a normal/standard dvd format so that I can play it on a normal DVD player?

---

EDIT:
I changed the wording a bit. We've a video in DVC-PRO HD 1080 but as far as I know it is a proprietary format. We'd like to create a standard dvd out of it. I'm not really in video encoding and dvd conversion. I thought I need to be more precise. VLC currently doesn't support DVC-PRO HD 1080.

Comment: more info on dvc-pro: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DV#DVCPRO_HD .. appears to be a professional format, descended from DV, somewhat along the lines of avc-hd, never made it in the consumer market.  your chances of finding a free tool is slim-to-none.

Answer (score 1):

[Quick Media Converter](http://www.cocoonsoftware.com/) is i have used for HD to DVD

You can find your best tools over here

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/sections/all-in-one-dvd-converters

Answer (score 1):

VLC?

I don't have any DVCPro HD footage to check, but VLC might be able to play and [transcode](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html) the footage.

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is the swiss army knife of AV conversion, but it is a command line tool. [Avanti](http://avanti.arrozcru.com/) is a GUI frontend. If the standard ffmpeg build doesn't work, try [ffmbc](http://code.google.com/p/ffmbc/).

Answer (score 1):

You should try at least once [Freemake Video converter](http://www.freemake.com/en/offline/offline_all/). It supports many formats and also has the ability to convert the audio.